# Filter data frame by value =+5 and -5 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset/filter my data in a certain way.  An example data frame is

```
strikeprice  underlyingprice
97           100
98           100
99           100
100          100
101          100
102          100
103          100
```

The aim is to filter the data where i have the values that fall between and including strikeprice+2 and -2.  The resulting data frame would look like this

```
98           100
99           100
100          100
101          100
102          100
```

Comment: `subset(mydataframe, underlyingprice >= strikeprice - 2 & underlyingprice <= strikeprice + 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat = data.table::fread('strikeprice  underlyingprice
97           100
98           100
99           100
100          100
101          100
102          100
103          100
', header=T)
```

```
dat %>% 
    dplyr::filter(underlyingprice >= strikeprice - 2 & underlyingprice <= strikeprice + 2)
```

```
1:          98             100
2:          99             100
3:         100             100
4:         101             100
5:         102             100
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `subset` + `abs`

```
> subset(df, abs(underlyingprice - strikeprice) <= 2)
  strikeprice underlyingprice
2          98             100
3          99             100
4         100             100
5         101             100
6         102             100
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[underlyingprice >= strikeprice - 2 & underlyingprice <= strikeprice + 2]
```